# Plot multiple fits lines in base graphics in r

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot multiple fitted lm lines in an only plot:

```
library(lme4)
fits <- lmList(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width | Species, data=iris)
coefs <- data.frame(coef(fits)); names(coefs) = c("Int", "slopes")
```

Then I plot all the fits at once via ggplot:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1,size = 0.5)+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept= Int , slope=slopes), color='grey', data=coefs)
```

Can someone help me to do it in the base graphics way?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)
lapply(fits, abline)
```

[image]